# Node . issue with starting up a discord bot

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, discord, discord.js

When I try and run `node .` in the terminal on visual studio no errors, nothing that indicates something wrong is happening. After I try and send `node .`, it loops and re-sends

> PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\advancius bot> .

Any suggestions?

**This is the current code I am using:**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'my token';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is Online');
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you run `node <filename>.js`? I don't know what `node .` does.

Comment: I had never heard of that either, but surprisingly I tried it and it worked.  I agree though that ``node filename.js`` will ensure you get what you want.

Comment: `node .` runs the file specified in the `main` field of `package.json` or `node index.js` if there is `index.js` in your cwd.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine.

In the console you have to specify the file like this: `node <filename>.js`.